# tdd - should I mock here or use real implementation

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, mocking

I'm writing program arguments parser, just to get better in TDD, and I stuck with the following problem. Say I have my parser defined as follows:

```
class ArgumentsParser {
    public ArgumentsParser(ArgumentsConfiguration configuration) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void parse(String[] programArguments) {
        // all the stuff for parsing
    }
}
```

and I imagine to have ArgumentsConfiguration implementation like:

```
class ArgumentsConfiguration {
    private Map<String, Class> map = new HashMap<String, Class>();

    public void addArgument(String argName, Class valueClass) {
        map.add(argName, valueClass);
    }

    // get configured arguments methods etc.
}
```

This is my current stage. For now in test I use:

```
@Test
public void shouldResultWithOneAvailableArgument() {
    ArgumentsConfiguration config = prepareSampleConfiguration(); 
    config.addArgument("mode", Integer.class);
    ArgumentsParser parser = new ArgumentsParser(configuration);
    parser.parse();
    // ....
}
```

My question is if such way is correct? I mean, is it ok to use real ArgumentsConfiguration in tests? Or should I mock it out? Default (current) implementation is quite simple (just wrapped Map), but I imagine it can be more complicated like fetching configuration from kind of datasource. Then it'd be natural to mock such "expensive" behaviour. But what is preferred way here?

EDIT:
Maybe more clearly: should I mock ArgumentsConfiguration even without writing any implementation (just define its public methods), use mock for testing and deal with real implementation(s) later, or should I use the simplest one in tests, and let them cover this implementation indirectly. But if so, what about testing another Configuration implementation provided later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Then it'd be natural to mock such "expensive" behaviour.

That's not the point.  You're not mocking complex classes.

You're mocking to isolate classes completely.

Complete isolation assures that the tests demonstrate that classes follow their interface and don't have hidden implementation quirks.

Also, complete isolation makes debugging a failed test much, much easier. It's either the test, the class under test or the mocked objects.  Ideally, the test and mocks are so simple they don't need any debugging, leaving just the class under test.

Comment: So you opt for focusing on Parser implementation completely just with defining Configuration interface only (and mock it up), and then create its implementation using completely independent tests?

Comment: @veilsoen: That is a common approach: independent development, independent testing.  The tradeoff occurs when you have a class that's so simple that the application class is just as simple as a Mock for application class.  This happens often in Java where an application class is just getters and setters; a Mock isn't really any simpler than the application class.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Seems really clear for now, but have one more question. What about dependencies that were created as a result of refactoring (applying SRP, etc)? Extracting them only causes that they are still used in tests. Should I also mock them out when I discover such "new" dependency?

Comment: @veilsoen: Yes, you need to test every class independently. For an abstract superclass or an interface, you create a concrete subclass or an implementation that is so trivial that it is effectively a mock class.

Comment: "Complete isolation assures that the tests demonstrate that classes follow their interface and don't have hidden implementation quirks." - but that also makes the test [coupled to the internal structure of the code](https://twitter.com/KentBeck/status/1182714083230904320) which is an implementation detail

Answer (score 5):

The correct answer is that you should mock anything that you're not trying to test directly (e.g.: any dependencies that the object under test has that do not pertain directly to the specific test case).

Answer (score 1):

In this case, because your ArgumentsConfiguration is so simple, I'd recommend using the real implementation until your requirements demand something more complicated.  There doesn't seem to be any logic in your ArgumentsConfiguration class, so it's safe to use the real object.  If the time comes where the configuration is more complicated, then an approach you should probably take would be not to create a configuration that talks to some data source, but instead generate the ArgumentsConfiguration object from that datasource.  Then you could have a test that makes sure it generates the configuration properly from the datasource and you don't need unnecessary abstractions.

Comment: I don't think I agree with this - it seems wrong to base your test of a class on the current implementation of a dependent class. What if later on ArgumentsConfiguration is changed to read from a properties file? The test of the parser will break. If you use a mocked ArgumentsConfiguration instead, the test will continue to work.

Comment: @SteveT This is definitely a matter of style, but mocking ArgumentsConfigurations is an overuse of mocking.  All it does is hold key/value pairs.  If ArgumentsConfiguration is read from a properties file, ArgumentsParser wouldn't have to change.  All that would have to change is the factory that creates ArgumentsConfiguration.  If you find that ArgumentsParser is dependent on where ArgumentsConfiguration gets created, then that's a smell indicating the design needs to be changed.  This is where I find that too much mocking can hide bad design.